# How to condense these lines into a single return statement?

Tags: python-3.x

In order to make my code more lisible, I need to find a way to shorten this expression using a '\n'.join method :

```
def __repr__(self):
        string = str()
        for row in self._map:
            string += ' '.join(row)+'\n'
        return string
```

edit : forgot to mention self._map was a list of lists of strings

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do so is :

```
return '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in self._map])
```

I think it's clearer this way than using a map() function and I heard it should also be faster since a lambda function is declared in the map() function.